# how do I pass string value to ProgressBar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-progressbar

```
pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBaradmin);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (pStatus <= 100) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pBar.setProgress(pStatus);

                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                    // Just to display the progress slowly
                    if (pStatus == str1) {
                        Thread.sleep(90000000);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                pStatus++;
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

I have an error in str1. It is mentioned in public string str1 in my class. How can I clear this error?

How do I pass string value to ProgressBar in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBaradmin);
        int d = Integer.parseInt(str2);
        pBar.setProgress(d);
```

This code work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the type of str1 first:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(str1) == pStatus)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: I got error unfortunately app has stopped @AmirHossein

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-185
                  Process: com.macappstudio.happyschool, PID: 3285
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                      at com.macappstudio.happyschool.Adminhomepage$8.run(Adminhomepage.java:158)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Application terminated.